# Is it conscientious to use a threshold for a model output in order to play on the recall and precision?

Tags: accuracy, f1score

I have just finished reading an article about the F1 score, recall and precision. Everything was clear except the fact that the author, in his example (see https://towardsdatascience.com/beyond-accuracy-precision-and-recall-3da06bea9f6c#a9f0), is using a threshold for his model output to play on the F1 score, recall and precision values.

So my question is: is it conscientious to use a threshold as the author did in his article?

In my opinion, this is like a kind of manual over-fitting, but maybe there is something I misunderstood...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Using a threshold is perfectly fine and is not "manual overfitting".

It is not *manual* because this is a step that can (and should) be done automatically. It is not *overfitting* as it doesn't modify the model itself. It modifies how you interpret the model's output.

What the user did is actual called **[cost-sensitive learning](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cost-sensitive-learning-for-imbalanced-classification/)**. It is a technique where you define which error is more *costly* and these costs are reflected in the performance metric you use.

I can see why it may feel like overfitting but it is important to understand that all you are doing here is handcrafting a performance metric with which you will evaluate your model. Your model will simply try to optimize this metric.

Comment: Thank for this helpful answer! :)
Just to be sure: even if you have an extreme threshold such as 0.2 or 0.8, it will not be a problem, because this threshold just changes the model output interpretation, right?

Comment: Indeed. The threshold can be "anything" between 0 and 1 and will only modify how you interpret the output, but won't change that output itself